# Using tkinter and grid to position buttons in an absolute manner

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to using tkinter and am struggling to get my buttons to render at the very bottom of the screen, evenly spaced out, filling the entire bottom row.

I have been using grid() to try to do this but no luck. I want these three buttons to render without impacting other components of the page(such as the text at the top). I am trying to accomplish a window that has three buttons, each button rendering a different page that you can interact with.

Here is my full code below, I appreciate any insight at all more than you know.

```
from cgitb import text
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
  
LARGEFONT =("Verdana", 35)
  
class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):
     
    # __init__ function for class tkinterApp
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         
        # __init__ function for class Tk
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
         
        # creating a container
        container = tk.Frame(self) 
        container.grid(row=0, column=0)
  
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0)
  
        # initializing frames to an empty array
        self.frames = {} 
  
        # iterating through a tuple consisting
        # of the different page layouts
        for F in (StartPage, Page1, Page2):
  
            frame = F(container, self)
  
            # initializing frame of that object from
            # startpage, page1, page2 respectively with
            # for loop
            self.frames[F] = frame
  
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky ="nsew")
  
        self.show_frame(StartPage)
  
    # to display the current frame passed as
    # parameter
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
  
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
         
        # label of frame Layout 2
        welcome = ttk.Label(self, text ="Welcome!", font = LARGEFONT)
        welcome.grid(row = 0, column = 2, )
  
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Page 1", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page1))
        button1.grid(row = 9, column = 1,  padx = 10, pady = 10)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Page 2", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page2))
        button2.grid(row = 9, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)

# second window frame page1
class Page1(tk.Frame):
     
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
         
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text ="Page 1", font = LARGEFONT)
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 2, )
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text ="StartPage", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.grid(row = 9, column = 1,  padx = 10, pady = 10)
  
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Page 2", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page2))
        button2.grid(row = 9, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
  
# third window frame page2
class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text ="Page 3", font = LARGEFONT)
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 2, )
  
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Page 1", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page1))
        button1.grid(row = 9, column = 1,  padx = 10, pady = 10)
  
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text ="Startpage", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button2.grid(row = 9, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
  
# Driver Code
app = tkinterApp()
app.geometry("800x425")
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the following changes to your code to get it working:

Gridded the root window so that `container` would occupy the entire space in the window.

```
#Gridding the tkinter window
self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
```

Made `container` expand in all directions using `sticky = 'nsew'`.

```
container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = 'nsew')
```

Modified `__init__` and added `tkraise` to all the *Page* classes.

I will use the below block of code for explanation purposes.

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        # label of frame Layout 2
        welcome = ttk.Label(self, text ="Welcome!", font = LARGEFONT)
        welcome.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
        
        #Creating a frame exclusively for the buttons
        self.frame_buttons = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.frame_buttons.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
        self.frame_buttons.grid_remove()
        
        #Gridding self.frame_buttons
        self.frame_buttons.grid_columnconfigure((0,1), weight = 1)
        self.frame_buttons.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        
        button1 = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text ="Page 1", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page1))
        button1.grid(row = 0, column = 0,  padx = 10, pady = 10)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text ="Page 2", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page2))
        button2.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        
    def tkraise(self):
        self.frame_buttons.grid()
        self.frame_buttons.tkraise()
        tk.Frame.tkraise(self)
```

In the `__init__` method, `self.frame_buttons` is created and all the buttons are added to it. It is displayed using `.grid` and then immediately removed with `.grid_remove()`. The advantage of using `.grid_remove()` is that the grid options are remembered and we can directly use `.grid()` to display the frame in future.

In the `tkraise` method, the frame is displayed, lifted to the top and then `tk.Frame.tkraise(self)` is used to call the in-built method.

[image]

### Working Code:

```
from cgitb import text
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
  
LARGEFONT =("Verdana", 35)
  
class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):
     
    # __init__ function for class tkinterApp
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         
        # __init__ function for class Tk
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        #Gridding the tkinter window
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
         
        # creating a container
        container = tk.Frame(self) 
        container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = 'nsew')
  
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
  
        # initializing frames to an empty array
        self.frames = {} 
  
        # iterating through a tuple consisting
        # of the different page layouts
        for F in (StartPage, Page1, Page2):
  
            frame = F(container, self)
  
            # initializing frame of that object from
            # startpage, page1, page2 respectively with
            # for loop
            self.frames[F] = frame
  
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky ="nsew")
  
        self.show_frame(StartPage)
  
    # to display the current frame passed as
    # parameter
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
  
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        # label of frame Layout 2
        welcome = ttk.Label(self, text ="Welcome!", font = LARGEFONT)
        welcome.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
        
        #Creating a frame exclusively for the buttons
        self.frame_buttons = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.frame_buttons.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
        self.frame_buttons.grid_remove()
        
        #Gridding self.frame_buttons
        self.frame_buttons.grid_columnconfigure((0,1), weight = 1)
        self.frame_buttons.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        
        button1 = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text ="Page 1", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page1))
        button1.grid(row = 0, column = 0,  padx = 10, pady = 10)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text ="Page 2", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page2))
        button2.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        
    def tkraise(self):
        self.frame_buttons.grid()
        self.frame_buttons.tkraise()
        tk.Frame.tkraise(self)

# second window frame page1
class Page1(tk.Frame):
     
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text ="Page 1", font = LARGEFONT)
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
        
        #Creating a frame exclusively for the buttons
        self.frame_buttons = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.frame_buttons.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
        self.frame_buttons.grid_remove()
        
        #Gridding self.frame_buttons
        self.frame_buttons.grid_columnconfigure((0,1), weight = 1)
        self.frame_buttons.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        
        button1 = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text ="StartPage", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.grid(row = 0, column = 0,  padx = 10, pady = 10)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text ="Page 2", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page2))
        button2.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        
    def tkraise(self):
        self.frame_buttons.grid()
        self.frame_buttons.tkraise()
        tk.Frame.tkraise(self)
  
# third window frame page2
class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text ="Page 2", font = LARGEFONT)
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
        
        #Creating a frame exclusively for the buttons
        self.frame_buttons = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.frame_buttons.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
        self.frame_buttons.grid_remove()
        
        #Gridding self.frame_buttons
        self.frame_buttons.grid_columnconfigure((0,1), weight = 1)
        self.frame_buttons.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        
        button1 = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text ="Page 1", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page1))
        button1.grid(row = 0, column = 0,  padx = 10, pady = 10)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text ="Startpage", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button2.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
        
    def tkraise(self):
        self.frame_buttons.grid()
        self.frame_buttons.tkraise()
        tk.Frame.tkraise(self)
        
# Driver Code
app = tkinterApp()
app.geometry("800x425")
app.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Note that new frame and buttons will be created whenever the new `tkraise()` function is executed.  It is not a good design.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for pointing it out. I have edited my answer now and given a more memory-efficient solution.

Comment: How can I set a height to the buttons? I thought it might be because I need to make the button frame larger but that seemed to do nothing. I can set the width to a button but not a height.

Comment: @acw1668 I figured out the height but I did notice a bug with your code. If you click off of your start screen and then back to start screen, the buttons do not have their original titles. It gets stuck on the startScreen button

Comment: @JustinPriede Adding `self.frame_buttons.tkraise()` after `self.frame_buttons.grid()` solves the problem. I have updated my answer as well.

Comment: @SriramSrinivasan thank you so much! I appreciate it more than you know. I am struggling to assign a background and foreground color to the ttk buttons as well? I have also tried bg and fg. Why can we not pass those in?

Comment: I have not used a `ttk.Button` much, so I am not very familiar with how to change the foreground and background colour. But if you want to add a `bg` and `fg`, you can use a `tk.Button` instead. It has many more configuration options than a `ttk.Button`.

Answer (score -1):

You are using grid along with pack. You should never mix these two layout managers as it results in unknown buggy behiviour. Maybe your code will work after culling that pack call.

Comment: I replaced the pack call but behavior seems the same

Comment: This line seems suspicious: welcome.grid(row = 0, column = 2, ) Also, you should use rowspawn and columnspawn attributes for a more customisable layout.